# Javascript - send and receive data from another domain

Tags: javascript, client-server

I'm trying to create a javascript plugin which needs the ability to send and receive data from  another domain.

Conceptually, the plugin is simple:

1. The users installs a piece of javascript code
2. The code communicates with central server (on another domain), sends some info about the user's site (a form of query) and get's some info back

The server domain would be fully under my control , but as you can see, end-users should be able to use the plugin just by installing a piece of javascript code.

Is this possible and if yes, what would be the simplest form of implementation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basic problem will be circumventing the same origin policy of JavaScript ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)). Basically you have two options, if you want to use only JavaScript on the client side:

1. **CORS** (cross-origin resource sharing): Here you enable the sharing on your domain and the JavaScript on the user's side will be able to interact with any data as if it was on their own server, thus you have no problems with the same origin policy. You can do AJAX request in the same way as if interacting with your own server. For details on how to activate this on your server environment see [here](http://enable-cors.org/). Note however, that this is not supported by older browsers see [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors) for details.
2. **JSONP**: All requests use the JSONP syntax. [Wikipedia on the topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)